# Head to tail rule of vector addition

Tags: vectors, geometry

Can then resultant vector pass through the vectors being added? Does the order in which place vectors according to head to tail rule matter?

let's suppose that vectors A and B are pointing east while C is pointing south. is it necessary that we place A and B first according to head to tail rule? because if place A first then C, then it gives a resultant vector that is passing through the vectors being added

Answer (score 1):

> Can then resultant vector pass through the vectors being added ?

Yes. The head to tail "rule" is just a visualisation of how vector addition works. The vectors that are being added do no actually move around.

> Does the order in which (we) place vectors according to head to tail rule matter ?

No, the order does not matter - in the same way as when we add $1$, $2$ and $3$ we always get $6$ no matter what order we add them in. A mathematician would say that vector addition is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). You can convince your self of this with a few trials, or for a more formal proof you can look at how vector addition works for each component of the resultant vector.

Answer (score 0):

The method is entirely for visualization of what vector addition means. I suppose one could call it an abstraction.

Here, you have taken the abstraction too far. IRL, vectors don't live in a position space, and there is no origin. Say we're adding electric field in 3D at some point/time: $E=(0,0,0)$ is not the origin, it's just the coordinates representation for the vector that is zero electric field.

If you add the non-zero components of $E$ (say from $N$ different charges $q_i$):

$$ \vec E = \vec E_1 + \cdots \vec E_N $$

the various terms can't "pass through each other"...it's just not a meaningful concept.

(It just occurred to me, that "passing through each other" is really a 2-dimensional problem anyway..., in fact:

You can have one dimensional vectors, say the forces on a rocket sled:

$$ \vec F_{total} = \vec F_{thrust} + \vec F_{drag} $$

Since it's one-D, we can drop the vectors and include a sign--but they are *still* vectors:

$$ F_{total} = F_{thrust} - F_{drag} $$

Pretty basic. Using the head to tail method, these vectors are passing through each other, which I hope is clearly meaningless.

)

Also: the original electric field equation above is unchanged by permutations of the labels $I\in[1,\cdot, N]$.